# How to import/export data in SQLite by using csv in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

How can I export/import data from SQLite to CSV in an Android app? I tried searching for Google but none of the code work for me.

Comment: You probably won't find an example of the complete operation on Google as it's not common on Android. Separate the operations : parse the csv files (easy) and write in sqlite using queries (easy too).

Comment: @dystroy : I am also facing the same issue.I want to convert the data from sqlite to excel. Have also asked the question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049323/android-program-to-convert-the-sqlite-database-to-excel#comment19415564_14049323 . but still I didn't got any positive response. Suggest me something if you know