# Excel To SQLite in android

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

I am working on a project where I have to save images in database using excel sheet. I mean how to store images in excel sheet and link that sheet to sqllite database?

Comment: Do you want to create it dynamically via your android code or you are Ok with the suggested answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export your Excel data to CSV format and Import from [Sqlite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) source CSV

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can import that Excel File in the 'SQLite Database Browser' (download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Create an external database, open your project and place that database file in your asset folder, then read from it.