# Can We Store Our SQlite DataBase Into PDF or Excel File?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm fairly new to Android,  I'm created simple CRUD operation app... now i want to  save my data base into SD card in pdf or excel format.. can we do this .. if yes.. then how to achieve it or not.. then why?

Comment: Check out this link and see if it help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049323/android-program-to-convert-the-sqlite-database-to-excel

Answer (score -1):

Of course no ?

why use PDF or Excel !!!

You will not able to CRUD any more on this file ? even if we suppose you use a 3rd lib to update this file on android , but why use a file , it will be hard and even very slow compared to sqlite..
and how to deal with relation between record in your database ?

I advise you to use sqlite or any ORM in android instead of file like PDF or Excel... and you can export from database later a PDF/EXCEL/etc ...