# How to forward tables of data from an android app to excel

Tags: java, android, excel, android-studio

I have an android app that displays data from different arrays within a table. This table is then displayed to the screen. I was wondering if there would be a way to forward the then populated data to excel or a text file where it would be usable. If there would be a totally different method to do this please let me know.

Comment: Are you thinking of doing pretty much the same thing that Google Sheets does?  Export your data to .xlsx?  If so, the format specs are available from Microsoft...

Comment: [Old SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448001/how-to-implement-export-sqlite-to-excel-csv-file-in-android) try this.

Comment: I don't know precisely what Google Sheets does but on its face, yes I want to export to xlsx. Could you post where exactly the specs are or some tutorial or example to follow...should I make an SQlite database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android program to convert the SQLite database to excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049323/android-program-to-convert-the-sqlite-database-to-excel)