# Firebase Database Data to Excel sheet

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an app using firebase database. There is 3 Child For every User. I want to get the 3 child and values in Excel sheet. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/ffc4f050cc489a0280eb7f4cbe36af07)

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer should help you.
[Android program to convert the SQLite database to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049323/android-program-to-convert-the-sqlite-database-to-excel/24221079#24221079)

In a nutshell you need to extract the data you want and use the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library to convert to csv.